# Using Laravel, how can I pass an include as an argument for another include?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 4.2 and I have multiple bootstrap boxes on my page. I would like to put those in a file that I can include along with some arguments that will be inserted into it, so I don't need to repeat the same code for the boxes every time.

**Controller**

```
$box_options = array(
    'icon_classes' => 'fa fa-pie-chart',
    'box_title' => 'Browser Usage',
    'box_footer_text' => 'View More Visitor Data'
  );

return View::make('index')->with('box_options', $box_options);
```

**box.blade.php** (Include File)

```
<div class="box box-default">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h3 class="box-title">
      <i class="{{ $icon_classes }}"></i> {{ $box_title }}
    </h3>
  </div><!-- /.box-header -->

  <div class="box-body">
    <div class="row">
      @include('includes.global.pie_chart', $browser_usage_pie_chart_options)
    </div><!-- /.row -->
  </div><!-- /.box-body -->

  @if($box_footer_text)
    <div class="box-footer text-center">
      <a href="javascript::;" class="uppercase">{{ $box_footer_text }}</a>
    </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
  @endif
</div><!-- /.box -->
```

I need the contents of the box body to be dynamic, so it could be either a string or another include file or a combination of both of them. If it was only a string, I could easily pass it in with the controller as I have with the other variables, but I need it to be able to place an include file there as well, except that it could a number of different include files.

How can I pass an include as an argument for another include? Or is there another completely different way to do this that I haven't considered?

Comment: AFAIK, all the variables accessible in the view will be accessible in all the includes inside the view as well. Not quite sure if that is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that's not what I'm asking. I am trying to put any content in the body, regardless if it is a string i'm passing in or another include file.

Comment: You can use `layouts` for that. Replace `include` in the body of your box with `yield('box-content')`, add `@extends('box.blade.php')` in the top of `includes.global.pie_chart` and wrap all its other content to `@section('box-content') ... @stop`. End now you can just include `includes.global.pie_chart` where you want and it will be wrapped to the box.

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov I'm not quite following but I think you may be on to something. Do you mind providing me an answer below along with sample code so I can see it?

Comment: As I'm reading your answer, I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. You mentioned adding @extends('box.blade.php') in the top of includes.global.pie_chart but I don't necessarily always want the pie_chart to be inside a box so I can't have it extend box.blade.php

Comment: Yep, in this case @layout is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

An `@include()` is like a php `include "";` so the scope of the variables don't change, you can acces the variables of `box.blade.php` in `includes.global.pie_chart` without passing it.
because the scope doesn't change, you can do:

```
return view('box', "browser_usage_pie_chart_options" => $browser_usage_pie_chart_options):
```

in your view **box.blade.php** have:

```
@include('includes.global.pie_chart')
```

and in **includes.global.pie_chart** call it like:

```
{{ $browser_usage_pie_chart_options }}
```

i recomend if  your includes are used many times and sometimes the variable doesn't exist, before print it check if exist `@if(isset($browser_usage_pie_chart_options))`

Comment: you mean `$browser_usage_pie_chart_options` can bea code or a string, depends of what the controller send?

Comment: Not exactly. The contents inside the box body can be a string or include any file.

Comment: Just a reminded that you may find on the web tutorials with: `return view('box', compact('browser_usage_pie_chart_options')):` Is the same as stated by Carlos but in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
@include("part.dateTemplate",["name" => "pr_date"])
 
// dateTemplate
  {{ $name }} // pr_date
```